# Android.mk - How to generate resource file on the fly

Tags: android, shell, android-source, android.mk

While build my APK in the AOSP environment, I want to create a temporary resource file which can be generated like this:

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><resources><string name=\"my_tmp_string\" translatable=\"false\">$SOME_ENV_VAR</string></resources>" > res/values/tmp.xml
```

However, put this in the Android.mk does not work.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try storing the command in a separate shell file like "*generate_res.sh*" for example, and afterward add a call to your Android.mk file like this:

$(info $(shell ($(LOCAL_PATH)/PATH_TO_FILE/generate_res.sh)))

Comment: Then how can I use $(LOCAL_PATH) in the shell script?

Comment: I haven't tried this myself yet, but you can always try passing it as an argument:

`$(info $(shell ($(LOCAL_PATH)/PATH_TO_FILE/generate_res.sh) $(LOCAL_PATH)))`
And in the script, get the argument using **$1**